# How to write a score that begins with a pickup note and repeats

Tags: notation, sheet-music, engraving, repeats, anacrusis

I'm writing a song as a score for piano and vocal. The verses begin with a pickup note on 4. So, after the chorus I end on 4 and then pickup up into the next verse with a repeat sign.

The question is:  Where do I write the pickup notes and lyrics after the chorus?
Writing the pickup to the next verse after the chorus and right before the repeat would make sense, but that is really awkward, since you have to go from there back to the beginning (FYI, there are 5 verses). Not very easy on the eyes. I'm just wondering if there is a standard approach to this.

Comment: My suggestion is to write the lyric in parantheses, ex ("so I..")  to show that it's starting on beat 4, then continue to write the rest as normal!

Comment: Do you actually need a repeat sign?  If there's no coda and no introduction, you probably do not.  Just shorten the last measure and end the piece with the usual double bar.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's clear: do you have (verse x5) then (chorus), or (verse then chorus) x5?

Answer (score 17):

You can do this two ways.   Do the first.  It really is clearer.

[image]

(How many verses are you going to make the singer(s) perform without a few bars rest though?)

Comment: In the absence of an introduction and a coda it's common, and probably better, to dispense with the repeat sign altogether.  In that case the last measure is shortened by the duration of the pickup measure, and the beginning of reach verse is printed at the beginning.

Comment: That's OK when making a simple reference lead-sheet of just the words and melody.  In a fuller arrangement for performance, the accompanying instruments probably need clearer instructions exactly what to play at the 'turn-round' endings and the actual end.

Comment: It applies equally to a lead sheet and to a piano-vocal score, which this question is about.  If different verses have different endings, then of course you need some way of notating that, but for most strophic songs there is no need for such complication.  People have been writing out such songs for centuries without repeat signs.

Comment: A slight modification of the first option is to duplicate the lyrics for the second and third verses under the initial pickup note as well. Makes it easier to read the lyrics, without the first syllable of the verse being in the wrong place.

Comment: That would be the second option!

Comment: @LaurencePayne Not quite, I keep the repeat in the sane position. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldLJW.png. Looks a bit silly for a short example, but helps for longer verses or convoluted repeat structures.

Comment: Having been a professional accompanist for a number of years, I can say I have *only* seen example one in a non-lead sheet setting. Many times, repeats and first/second endings, etc are on a different page than the start of the verse. The pick-up therefore is shown in the 1st ending/repeat. Also, while the first word of the next verses is not printed at the beginning of the verses, choral directors often suggest the singers write it in. If it is printed, it should be shown in parentheses so as to not confuse the singers as they come to the first verse.

Comment: @endorph - It might be nice to see that as a seperate answer.